# Output CSS, javascript and images with PHP

Tags: php, css, caching, redirect, assets

I was wondering if it's a good idea, and what are the drawbacks.

The reason I'm considering it is because I have a collection of themes outside of the web root directory and I'd like to keep them there because the application that runs the site is there too (themes are part of the app).

So I would link them normally, like:

```
site.com/views/images/bg.gif
```

And from .htaccess I redirect every request to a PHP script. The script finds the image inside the application theme folder and outputs it as `image/gif`, if the request starts with `views/`.

My thinking was that browsers will cache these files, so the performance impact should be pretty low, right? If I'm correct, is there anything I need to do to tell them to cache them?

Answer (score 1):

You could always create an Apache alias to map that external themes directory to inside your document root, e.g.

```
Alias /themes /path/to/theme/dir
```

and then have

```
<img src="/themes/foobar_theme/bg.gif" />
```

type stuff in your html. This way you can have the theme files outside your document root, still have them be accessible by direct URL, and remove the need to have PHP serve up everything.

Answer (score 0):

You should allow your web server to serve up static resources like CSS, scripts and images directly as this will reduce the CPU load server side and in turn reduce the latency of a request.

With careful configuration you can create virtual directories outside of your webroot if there is a need to keep these resources within your application hierarchy.

If you are dynamically generating any of these resources, or are restricting access to them based on calculated criteria then this answer does not apply.